# Crossvalidating for number of hidden layer nodes or not?

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation

I have come across a paper where the number of nodes in a one hidden layer neural network is being "empirically" derived as some function of the number of input and the number of output nodes. Since the number of nodes of the hidden layer is a hyperparameter of the model, I would assume that it would have to be crossvalidated for - or is the "empirical" approach also valid?

Thanks

Comment: It would really help if citation information, or the paper itself were available.

Comment: There can not be a rule  that works for every problem, just because of the inmense variety of problems and features that you can be in front of. There are rules like 2/3 of the inputs or things like that for simple nets but its precisely choosing parameters one of the difficulties of neural nets and other models with that kind of parameters.Cross validation or a similar method is better in my opinion.

Comment: @user777 here is the paper: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4301668/ the formula I am talking about is in the supplementary material, page 6

Comment: @D.Castro why would CV be better? I am not thinking only about the particular case of Neural Networks, but if I test my classifier correctly, is it not as well ok to start with some hyperparameters chosen a priori?

Comment: @Pegah but what if some other hyper parameter choices are better? If you're comfortable restricting yourself to some set of hyper parameter choices, that's fine. But otherwise....

Comment: @user777 yes I agree, I am just trying to understand. Particularly I was curious if an a priori choice somehow could lead systematically to overfitting, of if it is theoretically at least ok

Comment: Not *systematically.* the model could still be over- or under- fit, though.

Comment: @Pegah if you've tested some parameter for a problem then it's normal continuing with it, but only for that problem. With another problem you start again with othe features,measures, sizes etc.As there is no valid and magic formula the bestapproach is to test some grid of parameters.

Comment: @D.Castro "Best" is a huge overstatement. Grid search is stupidly simple to parallelize and it's exhaustive... but gtobal optimization with surrogate models or particle swarms can often find high-quality solutions with fewer function calls.

Answer (score 2):

Some people have "rules" about the relationship between the number of input and output nodes, but I'm not aware of any such rule which has a strong theoretical foundation.

The standard practice for this type of problem is to try lots of different configurations and measure performance on out-of-sample data.